# Should we encourage 3rd parties to harvest comments to create answers?

Tags: discussion

I just saw this Stack Overflow meta question [Is it correct to answer copying from comments by other users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304126) the leading answers essentially say, if there is good stuff in comments, go ahead and put it in a new answer (attribute comment maker as appropriate).

And given the last post to our meta is [Please refrain from using comments to answer](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2066) it seems like encouraging some of new users to look for gems in comments and work them into complete answers, could be a good thing.

We have a lot of old comments with valuable information that could lead to great answers, created by new users looking to contribute meaningfully to the project.

Comment: My vote is yes. <-- See what I did there? ;)

Comment: Also related: [Should we start flagging comments that are acting as answers?](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1870/should-we-start-flagging-comments-that-are-acting-as-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Based on a comment by Spiderman; I suggest we should encourage users to look for questions where there are good answers, parts of answers and/or supporting links in the comments and work to expand them into complete answers to the question.